# Why do we need that $f$ is continuous at $L$ to have $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(a_{n}) = f(L)$ when $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = L$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

> If $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = L $$
> and the function $f$ is continuous, then
>
> $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(a_{n}) = f(L)$$

I do not understand why do we have to indicate that $f$ is continuous at $L$. Can't we just say that $f$ is defined at $L$?

Comment: Being continuous is more than just being defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined as $f(x)=1$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Then with $L=0$, your statement does not hold for every sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n\neq 0$ for all $n$. This is precisely because $f$ is not continuous at $0$ although it is well defined on the whole real line (including at $0$).